# RSOD -  или красный экран смерти!!!

Tags: windows-7, boot

Случилось самое ужасное. Заказы, отпуск и тут такое!!!
Выбило чайником пакетник (весёлый у меня чайник)
Комп пишет boot failed!
Если нажать Enter, то выскакивает какое-то DOS окно - GRUB4DOS
И коммандная строка grub>_
А если нажать Escape, то О УЖАС!!! (я такого ни когда не видел!) **КРАСНОЕ ОКНО СМЕРТИ**!
В нём про SLIC Loader в основном написано.
Это всё? Или можно ещё побороться за жизнь wind'ы?

Comment: Можете фоточки экранов загрузить? Ну и это, загрузиться с линуксового загрузочного диска, посмотреть как там виндовские разделы.

Comment: по просьбам интернет-зрителям - фоточки!  ![alt text][1]![alt text][2]![alt text][3]  [1]: http://i.imgur.com/6GFV95k.jpg  [2]: http://i.imgur.com/pndkhPW.jpg  [3]: http://i.imgur.com/GQdBjsc.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Похоже загрузчик слетел, видимо у Вас ещё и мультизагрузчик был установлен... Восстановить можно попробовать. Как вариант установочным диском с виндой режим восстановления...

Comment: Поднял!!! Поднял я её!!!  Вотана, вотана! Windows моей мечты!!!  Мультизагрузчик скорее всего от "Windows 7 Loader eXtreme Edition v3.503" тот какие-то хитрые раздельчики создаёт для своих нужд, а так система одна.Поднял благодаря телефону!и 4-5 командам, брал их **[тут][1]**[1]: http://www.nestor.minsk.by/kg/2010/30/kg03013.html